# How to measure the execution rate in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, request, guzzle

For example, I have the following job in Laravel:

```
class MakeRequestBulkJob implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;

    protected $http_url;
    public $tries = 1;
    public $impress_count;

    /**
     * Create a new job instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($count)
    {
        $this->count = $count;
    }

    /**
     * Execute the job.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        $httpClient = new HttpClient();

        $url   = http_build_url(config('app.baseurl'),[
            'query' => [
                'id' => \uniqid()
            ],
            HTTP_URL_JOIN_QUERY
        ]);

        for($i=0; $i<$this->count;$i++){
            $requests[] = new Request('GET', $url);
        }

        $responses = Pool::batch($httpClient, $requests, array(
            'concurrency' => 100,
        ));

        $results = [];
        foreach ($responses as $res) {
            if(!isset($results[$res->getStatusCode()])){
                $results[$res->getStatusCode()] = 1;
            } else {
                $results[$res->getStatusCode()] = $results[$res->getStatusCode()] + 1;
            }
        }
        dump($results);
    }
}
```

Basically, It makes batch requests to the URL. I want to measure the average amount of requests and dynamically show it somewhere. Is there any tooling possible to use for that to get the precise value in real-time? I need just a couple of key words basically to look for on my own.

I'm planning to show it for a given time slice in the Zabbix server.

Comment: In any case you need to accumulate information somewhere. So one option is database of your choice, another option is logging through the file (using `Log` Facade for example) and another option - you can log requests directly to `Zabbix`.

Comment: Did you check [Laravel Horizon](https://horizon.laravel.com)?

Comment: Yes, but the point is that we use MySQL for a queue. Horizon is for Redis only, as I know.